# Clarity needed on SVM concepts

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, svm, scikit-learn

I've been reading up on articles and forums to understand how soft margin affects the classification of new data points, but I still couldn't connect the dots on how soft margin affects the outcome of the classification problem.

Several questions might help me to understand better if someone could assist. I will use the following image as my example.

[image]

1. Does a hard margin mean that no data point can fall within the margin?
2. What is the role of a soft margin? To determine the influence that each data point have on the the margin? Aka making the decision that misclassified data points should be less influential on the margin so that these misclassified points can't act as a support vector.
3. Even with a soft margin, the only factor that influences the classification of new data points is still the decision boundary ain't it? E.g., I added an orange and purple point on the right image. Orange will still ended up being classified as "Red" while purple as "Blue". Thus, does it mean that a soft margin will not affect the classification of new data points but it is only used for the sake of building the model?

Comment: To have a hard margin you need a separating hyperplane. Often that will not be possible (as in your second diagram - look at the red point on the left) which is why you would use a soft margin.